# Which subtype of Dynamic Programming is suitable for Python - Top Down or Bottom Up?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I have just started with Dynamic Programming. I want to know which subtype of Dynamic Programming is suitable for Python - Top Down or Bottom Up? This question is specifically for Python since I want to take care of the language characteristics.

Someone had told me that since Python doesn't have tail call elimination it might not be better for Top Down subtype since it is based on recursion and creates new frames for every recursion. So, it might increase the time complexity asymptotically. This is not so in Bottom Up. I am still not able to decide which subtype of DP is the most suitable for Python. Can you advise me on this on the basis of space and time expenses and complexity?

**Edit:** To clarify my problem, I'm adding some examples. I've tried Fibonacci here.

```
def top_down(n, memo={}):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return n
    elif n in memo:
        return memo[n]
    else:
        memo[n] = top_down(n-1, memo) + top_down(n-2, memo)
        return memo[n]

def bottom_up(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for _ in range(n-1):
        a, b = b, a+b
    return b
```

After this, I wrote two `timeit`'s. Here are the results.

```
>>> timeit.timeit('memo.clear(); top_down(100, memo);', setup, number=100000)
6.46689930770529
>>> timeit.timeit('bottom_up(100);', setup, number=100000)
0.9449206890500932
```

These are the testcases, I ran. The top one clears the `memo` on every run. The lower one is a `bottom_up` implementation and takes 1/6th of the time and is 6 times more efficient. This is what I meant. One can see an clear difference between their running times. I've tried many other problems and it seems that the Bottom Up implementation is always faster.

Thanks.

Comment: Neither! That's not how it works. A programming language doesn't really *favor* one or the other type. Both are perfectly viable. You're essentially a novice painter asking if a given canvas is more suitable for landscape imagery or portraits.

Comment: @Aerovistae So you mean that there won't be any *noticeable* difference even for large numbers?

Comment: That is correct. It depends on the problem, not the language. It would make more sense to ask which is more suitable for solving a given problem. Python is merely clay, it does anything.

Comment: There will not be any noticeable differences based on the language, there will obviously be differences based on the specific problem.

Comment: @Aerovistae I've updated my question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have the energy to go about forming an answer for this. Maybe @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen will explain.